# QTimer vs time.sleep in PySide programming

Tags: python, pyside

Here is a simple gui timer using PySide:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import time

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

try:
    message = """
    <pre>
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    </pre>
    """

    now = QTime.currentTime()
    due = now.addSecs(2)

    if not due.isValid():
        raise ValueError

    dueMs = now.msecsTo(due)

except:
    pass


label = QLabel("<b>" + message + "</b>")
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
QTimer.singleShot(dueMs, label.show)
QTimer.singleShot(3000, app.quit)
app.exec_()
```

Here is another version working equally well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import time

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

try:
    message = """
    <pre>
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    Alert! Alert! Alert!
    </pre>
    """

    now = QTime.currentTime()
    due = now.addSecs(2)

    if not due.isValid():
        raise ValueError


except:
    pass

while QTime.currentTime() < due:
    time.sleep(0.2)

label = QLabel("<b>" + message + "</b>")
label.setWindowFlags(Qt.SplashScreen)
label.show()
QTimer.singleShot(3000, app.quit)
app.exec_()
```

The difference is that the second version uses time.sleep while the first version uses QTimer.singleShot for the timing. Is one of them to be preferred to the other? If so, why?

Comment: QTimer.singleShot also connects to other threads while time.sleep doesn't. Also time.sleep probably makes the rest of your programm unresponsive. Have you tested, that it is still responsive? For more complex applications I would always prefer QTimer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is one of them to be preferred to the other? If so, why?

**Answer** : It's hard to say what is right or wrong. My opinion, For purpose of your application used.

---

Let's say, in situation : "Load data before start"

Your have to load mass-data into the main application. It will take a long time to finish loading. The point is you have the load completed before start. So in your `second version` it should be good to use it. But if your not wait this delay, you should create thread to load data and trig your label until completed load. As as the `first version` (See is work just-like QThread).

In other situation : "Save data in application"

You have to save mass-data from main application into file. It's takes time to write the file. If your use `first version`. When the user tries to save, the applicationstarts to save the file. The time until save is completed your application can't do anything (such as black transparent screen in Ubuntu, hang or freeze occurs). But if you use `second version`, your have to handle when start save, cancel and completed save file. So hard but good in application response to user.

Comment: Just a comment on your use of the English language. Often you write "your" when it should be "you" (You have to..). You use too often have (It needs a lot of time). And you sometime do not use a form of be/a/the. (It is so hard but it is good in an application to respond to the user.) And many more. The answer is difficult to understand only because the English is hard to follow. If you improve the language your answers will be even more useful. :)

Comment: @neuronet Is possible and maybe I'll do but improving your own proficiency in the English language should still have very high priority for everyone.

Comment: @Trilarion good point. I tried to edit it some, but frankly I am starting to appreciate just how bad it is now that I tried to actually make sense of it.